# Remove Add New Address and delete buttons on adminhtml

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml, overrides, address

I want to remove these 2 buttons denying the ability to create or delete addresses.

[image]

How Magento renders this layout? It seems it has to be this file: `/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

There is the definition of Customer and Addresses fieldset, but where are defined these 2 buttons: add new addresses and delete?

I only can see this:

```
<fieldset name="address">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Addresses</item>
            <item name="removeMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
(...)
```

The removeMessage is the text displayed when you try to delete an address. But how I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wonderful examples of over-complicated component which moved from specific module to `Ui`.

So, as you can see `is_collection` option specify (`\Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs::addChildren`) that for this fieldset will be used special component for collections `Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection`.

This component have template `template: 'ui/form/components/collection'`.
Component template contains blocks, which you want to remove

*Remove address button*

```
<div class="address-list-item-actions">
    <button class="action-delete" type="button" click="$parent.removeAddress.bind($parent, $data)">
        <span text="$parent.removeLabel"/>
    </button>
</div>
```

*Add new address button*

```
<li class="address-list-actions last">
    <button class="scalable add" type="button" click="addChild">
        <span text="addLabel"/>
    </button>
</li>
```

So, you can rewrite this template using custom template for fieldset component.

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">My_Module/my/custom/template</item>
        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="removeMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: I see, but this class `collection` is not used by another context? I will not break something else?

Comment: @slayerbleast my answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that with css by setting the buttons to display none

```
.address-list .address-list-actions {
      display:none; 
}

.address-list .action-delete  {
      display:none; 
}
```

Otherwise the reference template to remove them is the following which you have to override

```
/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/components/collection.html
```